# Undefined method error while running rspec test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

All,

I am getting the following undefined method errors below when running my rspec tests.  When I have gotten this error before I had a method misspelled or my order of execution caused it.  I checked both along with some other posts on StackOverflow, but nothing helped.  Can anyone offer any guidance?

**Rspec Failures:**

```
FFFF

Failures:

1) Post vote methods #up_votes counts the number of votes with value = 1
 Failure/Error: expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `up_votes' for #<Post:0x007fe92f381a38>
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) Post vote methods #down_votes counts the number of votes with values = -1
 Failure/Error: expect(@post.down_votes ).to eq(2)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `down_votes' for #<Post:0x007fe92a18c228>
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 3) Post vote methods #points returns the sum of all down and up votes
 Failure/Error: expect(@post.points ).to eq(1) # 3 - 2
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `points' for #<Post:0x007fe92986c620>
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 4) Vote validations value validation only allows -1 or 1 as values
 Failure/Error: expect(@post.up_votes).to eq((-1) || eq(1))
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `up_votes' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:5:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Post_rspec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Post do
 describe "vote methods" do

 before do
  @post = Post.create(title: 'Post title', body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.')
  3.times { @post.votes.create(value: 1) }
  2.times { @post.votes.create(value: -1) }
 end

describe '#up_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with value = 1" do
    expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
  end
end

describe '#down_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with values = -1" do
    expect(@post.down_votes ).to eq(2)
  end
end

describe '#points' do
  it "returns the sum of all down and up votes" do
    expect(@post.points ).to eq(1) # 3 - 2
  end
end
end
end
```

**vote_spec file**

```
describe Vote do
 describe "validations" do
  describe "value validation" do
  it "only allows -1 or 1 as values" do
    expect(@post.up_votes).to eq((-1) || eq(1)) 
  end
 end
 end
 end
```

**Post.rb**

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :votes
 has_one :summary
 belongs_to :user #means the post table has the user table's primary key in it
 belongs_to :topic
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}

 validates :title, length: {minimum: 5},  presence: true
 validates :body,  length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true



def markdown_title
(render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
end


def markdown_body
(render_as_markdown).render(self.body).html_safe
end

private

def render_as_markdown
renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
extensions = {fenced_code_blocks: true}
redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
#return redcarpet
 end


 end
```

Comment: What are `up_votes`, `down_votes` & `points`? Are they attributes in posts table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `post_spec.rb` errors, check the `Post` model (see file `app/models/post.rb`) has the following methods defined in it:

- `up_votes`
- `down_votes`
- `points`

Consider including the code for `post.rb` in your original question too.

For the `vote_spec.rb` errors, there is no `@post` variable, it will be `nil`. This error message hints at this:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@post.up_votes).to eq((-1) || eq(1))
NoMethodError: undefined method `up_votes' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Thank you Eliot.  I have posted the post.rb file up above.